# The name "'IMGUserLabel' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

This is where the IMGUserlabel is located at in the .Apsx :

[image]

This is the Aspx.Cs :

```
public void GetUserDetails(int id)
{   
    string getUserDetail = "Select ID,Email,Name,Country,Convert(varchar (20), RegisterDate, 106) RegisterDate,Convert(varchar (20), LastLogin, 106) LastLogin ,Description,ImageName FROM [User] where Id='" + id + "'";

    dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserDetail);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        IMGUserLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        NameLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        UserImage.ImageUrl = "~/UserImage/" + dt.Rows[0]["ImageName"].ToString();
        lblCreated.Text = dt.Rows[0]["RegisterDate"].ToString();
        LabelLastLogin.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastLogin"].ToString();
        lblCreated.Text = dt.Rows[0]["RegisterDate"].ToString();
        LabelAboutMe.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
    }
}
```

And The Error is Displayed : The name "'IMGUserLabel' does not exist in the current context"   However the other labels display the data correctly

Ok i have added this, And there is no Errors :) however no data is being displayed on the Label , it just says "Label" :

```
void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    string getUserDetail = "Select ID,Email,Name,Country,Convert(varchar (20), RegisterDate, 106) RegisterDate,Convert(varchar (20), LastLogin, 106) LastLogin ,Description,ImageName FROM [User] where Id='" + e + "'";
    {
        // Retrieve the Label control in the current DataListItem.
        Label IMGUserLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("IMGUserLabel");
        IMGUserLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This is the Result , label is supposed to display the user of that image 
[image]

Comment: is the label inside a repeater or something of the sort?

Comment: Almost feels like the declaration for that control didn't make it into the designer.cs or eqiv.

Comment: Its inside a <Datalist> <ItemTemplate>  Here  </ItemTemplate> </Datalist>

Comment: and the lblCreated and Name label are inside that same datalist/ itemtemplate?

Comment: And no lblCreated and Name label not inside the datalist/ itemtemplate

Comment: i have updated the code please check

Comment: Does the updated code even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer ,it was all along:

```
 IMGUserLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name".]ToString();
```

Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

lblCreated and NameLabel are working because they are defined outside of your DataList. To access IMGUserLabel from within your method, you need to find it inside your DataList first.

```
Label IMGUserLabel = (Label)e.FindControl( "IMGUserLabel");
IMGUserLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
```

'e' is the DataListItemEventArgs instance from your DataBound event handler. You'll need to either modify your GetUserDetails method to take in the DataListItemEventArgs instance or pass in the Label instance directly.

Comment: It now says "the name e does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You're probably binding the header in that part. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx